# How to update a specific JSON element inside a complex JSON document in postgresql 10

Tags: json, postgresql

I have `JSON document` which is stored under single column of type `jsonb` inside `postgresql` which looks like below:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "type": "transaction",
  "entry": [
    {
      "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:100",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Encounter",
        "id": "110",
        "status": "planned",
        "priority": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "code": "ASAP"
            }
          ]
        },
        "subject": {
          "reference": "Patient/123"
        },
        "appointment": [
          {
            "reference": "Appointment/12213#42"
          }
        ],
        "diagnosis": [
          {
            "condition": {
              "reference": "Condition/condReferenceValue"
            },
            "use": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/diagnosis-role",
                  "code": "AD"
                },
                {
                  "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/diagnosis-role",
                  "code": "DD"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "hospitalization": {
          "preAdmissionIdentifier": {
            "system": "https://system.html"
          }
        },
        "location": [
          {
            "location": {
              "display": "Mumbai"
            },
            "status": "active"
          },
          {
            "status": "planned"
          }
        ]
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "Encounter"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to update value for `reference` under `subject` attribute. So, I tried below way but it throws an error:

```
update fhir.testing set names = jsonb_set(names,'{"subject":{"reference"','"Patient/1"',true) where id = 10;
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal: "{"subject":{"reference""
  Detail: Unexpected array element.
```

I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype) but didn't work out for me. How can I do it?

Comment: Please, if you are asking about **postgresql** don't tag as **mysql**

Comment: Removed [tag:mysql] tag.

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009837

Comment: is the json document stored under the name `names` and has type jsonb?

Comment: Yes @PeterDarmis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct Query for your requirement is:

```
update fhir.testing 
set names= jsonb_set(names, '{entry,0,resource,subject,reference}', '"Patient/1"' , false) 
where id = 10;
```

**Explanation**

`json_set` takes 4 parameter

1. target_json (jsonb) - which accept `jsonb` type data. In your case it is `names` field.
2. path (text[]) - which accepts a text array. in your case it is '{entry,0,resource,subject,reference}'.
3. new_value (jsonb) - in your case you want to change it to `'"Patient/1"'`.
4. create_missing (boolean) - in your case it should be `false`. as you want to replace the existing one. if you want to create the reference with given value in case of not found then just mark it `true`.

Comment: Yeah this worked for me @Akhilesh. Also, I was little bit curious for understanding that is there way that I could make it generic. Like, by creating a function which will take the input parameter, search in the JSON doc and update the value by passing some second parameter to that function. Just need some hint

Comment: Also, what does `0` indicates in that text array. I am new to PostgreSQL so, trying to understand things

Comment: 1. Yes it is possible a little bit effort is required.     2. As you can see that `entry` is an array, so `0` denotes first object of `entry` array and `resource,subject,reference` denotes the path in it

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022189/retrieving-json-elements-with-a-specific-key-name-from-a-complex-nested-structur)

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Postgres that much but from what i read in the relative `jsonb_set` example in the documentation of [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) (and since you want to update) shouldn't it be

```
jsonb_set(names, '{entry,0,subject,reference}','Patient/1', false)
```

instead of

```
jsonb_set(names,'{"subject":{"reference"','"Patient/1"',true)
```

***jsonb***

> *jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_missing*
> *boolean])*
>
> Returns `target` with the section designated by `path` replaced by
> `new_value`, or with `new_value` added if `create_missing` is **true** (*default*
> *is true*) and the item designated by `path` does not exist. As with the
> path oriented operators, negative integers that appear in `path` count
> from the end of JSON arrays.

**EDIT**

To explain the `path` used in `jsonb_set`, check this example.

```
jsonb_set('[{"f1":1,"f2":null},2,null,3]', '{0,f1}','[2,3,4]', false)
```

returns

```
[{"f1":[2,3,4],"f2":null},2,null,3]
```

As i understand if a sub-element in a complex JSON document is an array, you need  to specify it's index e.g. 0,1,2,...

**EDIT**

Always look very carefully the structure of the JSON document. I simply write this because i did not see that **subject** was a child of **resource** and that is causing you the error.

***So the correct path is actually '{entry,0,resource,subject,reference}'***

Comment: When I tried to use your way it throw an below error `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: ... = jsonb_set(names, '{entry,0,subject,reference}','Patient/1...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Token "Patient" is invalid.`

Comment: You are correct, i am sorry for this mistake. I have not seen that subject was a child of resource. So the query fails because the path is incorrect. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

the value is not valid json, try this out:

```
update fhir.testing set names = jsonb_set(names, '{"entry": [{"resource": {"subject":{"reference":"Patient/1"} }}]}',true) where id = 10;
```

You have to create a valid json, closing every { and every ], yours was

```
'{"subject":{"reference"'
```

Comment: When I try your query it says that `jsonb_set` doesn't exist